# Theme default Colors FG and BG for both editing and compare makes elements never seen

Tags: colors, comparison, aptana

I am quite newbie.
After I have installed Studio3 plugin Eclipse, I got some problems of colors with Default Theme.

In these for the moment I have a not workaround situation while using the "Text compare" because I could not find how two change the color of elements which have the same color as background "black".

When black background is used, as the comparison mode uses black as default color for many elements they are hidden. I made some test with a variant grey background to find the elements, it obviously can't be used for normal use.

**Where are the template definition for "comparison mode" seems the main question ?**

**The minimum to reach is that the black ForeGround colored elements (defined surely for white background) become white with a black background.**

**Elements of analysis :**
The changes on other elements are taken in account in comparison mode (and obviously in edit mode which functions normally), but the elements that are not taken in account in comparison mode are black by default. So I look at a default color for not held elements, I could not find such an item. The default values that I found, and that I declared FG white, have no effect.

Thanks for help.

Trebly

Aptana Studio 3.0.7
No changes done to default parameters
*context :* Php 
*black elements in compare mode :* vars; functions calls; names; syntax base;
*hold elements :* text; keywords (var, function, parent, class, extends, array, empty....); comments

Answer (score 0):

After quite long search :

When Aptana studio3 plugin is installed, the default theme can not be well setup for others editors than Aptana such as standard comparison if you use the Aptana studio3 theme. Then you get incoherent display. The solution is simple.

**To get everything right, if the application is able to hold new Aptana theme management, you must simply :**
1- change the default Aptana studio3 theme for example for ECLIPSE (Base) theme
2- Change again to Aptana studio3 theme, this will reset all elements of themes (for various compatible editors)

Note : **SmartyPDT (and others not tested probably) are not compatible with the theme management of Sudio3**, in such case you need to stay with another theme as Studio2 (theme option in studio3). In fact the defined colors are compatible with studio2, particularly black standard text (which was default color). The incompatibility makes that you get a not a coherent fit of colors which lead to incoherency, which can't be avoided, worse black on black... for some text-elements.

Trebly